# Parse any json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, reactjs

i want to parse any json in javascript (react more exactly) and put it in a big object (to show it on UI and modify before put it again in json)
But i don't know how to exactly do that !

I tried with 
`var data =  require("./test.json");
      var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);`

But after that i don't know how to parse correctly my file,i can't name programaticaly my properties in my array so impossible to parse manually..

I precise i don't know json content so i can't do pre-build object.
Thank you for you answers ! :)

Comment: Something like http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/ ?

Comment: Are you looking for `JSON.parse(data)`?

Comment: `var data =  require("./test.json");` — This does parse it

Comment: `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(data);` — This **un**parses it and turns it back into JSON

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say in the rest of the question.

Comment: Well, not much of an idea. I suspect this is a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve when stringifying the data? `JSON.stringify` turns JSON object to a string.

Comment: @haipham23 — There's [no such thing as a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). `JSON.stringify` turns a **JavaScript** object (or primitive) into a string of JSON.

Comment: @Quentin, https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp

Comment: @haipham23 — http://www.w3fools.com/ — W3Schools is terrible. Don't trust them.